# PDO handle error with query() or with prepare() method

Tags: php, pdo

What is better(faster) way to handle, if there is an error with executed SQL?

using PDO's `query()` method:

```
$db_conn->query("some sql"); 
if ($db_conn->errorInfo()[2] !== NULL) {
    // there is error 
}
```

or with `prepare()` method:

```
$sth=$db_conn->prepare("some sql");
$sth->execute();
if ($sth->errorInfo()[2] !== NULL) {
    // there is error 
}
```

I mean case, when there is no need to care about SQL Injections and when there is no repeated queries.

Are they same at performance point of view? and if yes, is then better to use `query()` variant, because there is  little bit  less code ?

Comment: From my understanding, using prepare/execute will take an extra call to the database, query only takes 1.  Although this is probably trivial it is a difference.  Although I tend to stick with prepare/execute as it becomes a standard in my own code.

Comment: One thing to point out is that in your second example, if your not using exceptions, you should be checking if `$sth` is false as this means the prepare has failed.  So you must check for an error at each point (or use exceptions).

Comment: My personal preference is to ***ALWAYS*** use prepare/execute. That way you don't risk opening up a security hole if you change the source of data being used in a query at a later date to that submitted by a user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to use exceptions. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

```
$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then later:

```
try {
    $sth=$db_conn->prepare("some sql");
    $sth->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```